# Centralize a div in the remaining horizontal space of its' parent div

Tags: jquery, html, css

On my site I have a side navigation bar which you can hide, I also have a main central div which will contain a payroll calculator. I want this div to be horizontally centralized at all times. But as of now it is ignoring the `navbar` and basing its' position off of the parent div only.

### **[fiddle here shows entire thing:](http://fiddle.jshell.net/vz4srfe0/2/)**

I'm guessing once it is behaves so it centralized properly, it will adjust when the side bar is hidden.

This is the html for the page structure:

### **HTML**

```
<div id="Main">


        <div id="content">

            <div id="navBar">
                <div class="navBtn navBtnText">
                    Calculator
                </div>
                <div class="navBtn navBtnText">
                    About
                </div>
                <div class="navBtn navBtnText">
                    Services
                </div>
            </div>

        <div id="Content-header">
            <div id="navBar-control">
                <a href="#" id="toggle-slide-button">
                    <img src="Images/menu_default.png" onmouseover="this.src='Images/menu_hoverr.png'" onmouseout="this.src='Images/menu_default.png'" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span>Calculator</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="calc-box">
        </div>

        </div>


    </div>
```

### **CSS**

```
#Main { 
    width: 1164px;
    height: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 0px;

    background-color: white;
} 
}

 #navBar{   
    background-color: #660000;
    height: 100%;
    width: 85px;
    float: left;
}


#logo{
    width: 132px;
    height: 60px;

    background-image: url(Images/ADPHeaderLogo.png);
    background-size: contain;
}

.navBtn{    
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.2);
    opacity: 1;

    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
}

.navBtnText {
    line-height: 120px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.navBtn:hover{
   background-color:#990000;
}

#navBar-control {
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    float: left;
}

#content {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}

#Content-header {
    padding-top: 15px;
    width: auto;
}

#calc-box {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 15px;
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    height: 500px;
    width: 50%;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}
```

The other div in the content div is float left and hits and stops ta the nav bar and moves with it, the same for the calc div if I set it to float left, but I don't understand why the margin ignores it and bases its' position off of the parent only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other answer said: " A floated element breaks out of the positioning flow of it's parent, so #content ignores it while calculating margins. "

So, in order to set the exact margin to the calculator div when the sidebar is active, get the half the width of the sidebar and set this value as an offset to left for the calculator div.

```
var real_mar = $('#navBar').width() / 2;
real_mar = real_mar + "px";
```

For the sake of giving an example, I added position relative to the calculator div and used jQuery to add/remove value for left property of the calc div

```
#calc-box {
position: relative;
}

$("#toggle-slide-button").click(function () {
    if (!state) {
        $('#navBar').animate({width: "toggle"}, 200);
        $('#calc-box').css({"left":"0px"}); // remove the offset
          state = true;
        }
    else {
        $('#navBar').animate({width: "toggle"}, 200);
        $('#calc-box').css({"left":real_mar}); // add the offset
        state = false;
        }
});
```

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://fiddle.jshell.net/vz4srfe0/7/)**

Answer (score 1):

A floated element breaks out of the positioning flow of it's parent, so `#content` ignores it while calculating margins.

See this : http://fiddle.jshell.net/vz4srfe0/4/

things to note:

- `Main` has property `clear:both`
- `#navBar` and `#content` have property `float: left`
- `#content` width is calcualted as `calc(100% - 85px)` , since `navBar` has width `85px`

**EDIT**

Visual trickery made me think the above worked - however, it will centre only when the nav is open. Not sure if this is possible with just CSS - how about adding a class with your javascript that adjusts the width of `#content`? http://fiddle.jshell.net/vz4srfe0/6/

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap your calc-box and Content-header with a div, like this:

```
<div id="inner">
    <div id="Content-header">
        <div id="navBar-control">
            <a href="#" id="toggle-slide-button">
                <img src="Images/menu_default.png" onmouseover="this.src='Images/menu_hoverr.png'" onmouseout="this.src='Images/menu_default.png'" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>Calculator</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="calc-box">
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you have to add a margin-left to #inner in your CSS, as a default value, which has to be equal to your navigations width:

```
#inner{
    margin-left: 85px;
}
```

Finally you have to change your jQuery-Code, so it changes the margin-left, when you toggle your navigation:

```
var state = false;

$("#toggle-slide-button").click(function () {
    if (!state) {
        $('#navBar').animate({width: "toggle"}, 200, 'swing', function(){
            $('#inner').css('margin-left', '0');
            state = true;
        });
    }
    else {
        $('#navBar').animate({width: "toggle"}, 200, 'swing', function(){
            $('#inner').css('margin-left', $('#navBar').css('width'));
            state = false;
        });
    }
});
```

See here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/vz4srfe0/5/